# How can I ignore previous selection and write only last selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The html code is;

```
                        <div>
                            <label>Categories
                                <select id="projectSelect" class="list_who_to_mail" name="projectSelect"></select>
                            </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <input name="projectID" id="projectID" type="hidden"></input>

                      <div>

                        <div>
                            <label >Discipline
                                <select name="disciplineSelect" id="disciplineSelect" class="list_who_to_mail"> </select>
                            </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>        
                            <input name="categoryID" id="categoryID" type="hidden"></input>  

                     <div>

                        <div>
                            <label >Main Group
                                <select name="main" id="main" class="list_who_to_mail">
                                <option></option>
                                <option>Technical</option>
                                <option>Contracts</option>
                                <option>Procurement / Logistics</option>
                                <option>Administrative</option>
                                <option>Financial</option>
                                <option>Legal</option>
                            </select>
                            </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div >

                        <div >
                            <label>Effect on (Part 1)
                            <select name="observedPhase[]" id="observedPhase" multiple="multiple" class="list_who_to_mail" size="13">

                                <option>Warranty</option>
                                <option>Operability</option>
                                <option>Reliability</option>
                                <option>Reputation</option>
                            </select>
                            </h5></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

the function is;

```
$(function () {
        $('.list_who_to_mail').on('change', function() {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");


            var value = $("#"+id).val();

            $("#list_mail").append(value);
        });
    });
```

The concept is when user clicks on the select fields function will collect ids of fields and with these ids it will list emails in "#list_mail".

The question is; when I click any option values all ids are writing side by side in the div. How can I ignore previous selection and write only last selected id of every option on the div? Considering "disciplineSelect", name="main", categoryID" and "observedPhase[]".

Thanks in advance

Edit: language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overwrite any previous value you should set the `html()` of the element, not `append()` a new string value. Try this:

```
$('.list_who_to_mail').on('change', function() {
    $("#list_mail").html($(this).val());
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uqv3n458/)

Note that you can also shorten your code as `this` is a reference to the `select` that changed. You don't need to select it again by its `id`.

---

*Update*

If you want to get the selected value from each option, you can use `map()`:

```
$('.list_who_to_mail').on('change', function() {
    var values = $('.list_who_to_mail').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    $("#list_mail").html(values.join(','));
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uqv3n458/1/)

Comment: I wrote this code but it gets only last selected value, I want to get last selected value of every select option :/

Comment: @ZekiBayoglu that's not what your question asked...? `How can I ... write only last selected id on the div?`

Comment: missed one `.get()` after `.map()`

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks. I put it in the fiddle, forgot it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Don't use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/), use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
$(function () {
    $('.list_who_to_mail').on('change', function () {
        var value = $(this).val();

        $("#list_mail").html(value);
    });
});
```

Also in your change handler, `this` refers to the currently changed element so `this` can be used to get the jQuery wrapper for the changed element, no need to use the `id-selector`

Comment: I wrote this code but it gets only last selected value, I need to get last selected value of every select option hoe can I do it? @ArunPJohny